# Did Kylo Ren ever find this out?

Tags: star-wars, kylo-ren, the-last-jedi, princess-leia

Did Kylo Ren ever find out this bit of information?

> That his mother, General Leia, survived the earlier attack.

Comment: Unless they had a spy on the ship when everyone else was told her status (and given that they only learned of the escape plan from Finn) I doubt it...

Answer (score 4):

### Kylo Ren knows that his mother survived.

The film's junior novelisation confirms that after his famous duel with Luke, Kylo Ren senses both Rey and Leia boarding the Falcon.

> *He picked up two small objects from the ground. A pair of chance
> cubes, strung together. Ren knew the dice well. They had been Han’s,
> hanging in the cockpit of The Millennium Falcon.*
>
> ***Ren glimpsed the ship through the Force. Rey and Leia were boarding.**
> Both seemed upset by something.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Last Jedi: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 3):

Lots of spoilers

> The movie evokes *Return of the Jedi* (when Luke and Vader have a moment through The Force while on passing ships) in the moments before the attack. Kylo Ren can sense his mother on the ship (the camera switched back and forth between the two just as it did in ROTJ). He didn't hesitate with his father, but he can feel his mother through The Force... and then another fighter does the deed for him.
> Even with that distance between them after the attack, it's a pretty safe bet he could feel her when she uses The Force to reach out and pull herself back on board. In the off chance Ren didn't notice, there's almost no chance Snoke didn't, and he would have used it to make another dig at Kylo Ren (and gin up that anger Sith thrive on, just as he did in saying he was mistaken about Ren being another Vader).

Comment: This seems to be speculation at best. There's no indication that Snoke dug at Kylo about it or that Kylo had sensed her.

Comment: @Edlothiad Possibly. Maybe they were panning back and forth between Ren and Leia because Disney is contractually required to have a minimum number of scene transitions in every movie. But you have to admit, it's pretty hard to buy that two strong Force users a mere kilometer or two away couldn't sense another Force user *using The Force*, when both of them noticed Rey from light years away in TFA.

Comment: How do you know it was a kilometre or two? Sounds like more speculation to me. Leia was an active presence in the force. It's not like she suddenly gained force powers. She and long-standing abilities in the force.

Comment: For all we know (and I guess we won't know until the novelisation) Leia may have been actively reaching for Ben through the Force prior to the earlier attack, while she certainly wouldn't have been doing so while unconscious after the attack.

Answer (score 1):

We do not ever see him learn of this information on-screen.

That said, we have seen that people who are strong in the Force tend to ***know*** when someone close to them dies.

Kylo Ren obviously still has a connection to Leia, but we have no way of knowing if that connection was maintained after

> Leia was ejected into space.

It's certainly possible that Kylo knew

> She had survived that

but it isn't clear to me if he was aware that she

> Made it to the salt-covered planet with the transports.

Leia certainly doesn't seem to think he will be aware, given that she

> remains confident that the First Order will not realize the Rebels evacuated to the secret base

but DOES, in her later conversation say

> that she knows Kylo is beyond salvation, and is entirely committed to the First Order.

Thus, we must assume that she had reason to think he expected her to be dead or was otherwise unable to locate her via the Force.  Perhaps she took steps to hide her presence?

This is not to say, however, that Kylo would not become aware of

> Leia's survival

after the events of the movie.  Given that the Rebel leadership tends to be known by the Empire/First Order leadership, it's fair to assume that the renewed Rebellion would make no secret of her status.